# mercurial hg partial checkin

Tags: version-control, mercurial

It is a very simple and stupid question,

I am working on 2 tasks and modified 2 sets of files in the code.

Now when I type 'hg ci', it checks in all the files. Can I remove certain files from the checkin i.e. do checking for only one task?

If I remove the files in the 'check in message' will they be removed from the checkin

Thanks for all the answers

This seems like a big flaw, My use case is very simple and general. Most of the time dev are working on various tasks , some are ready , some are not, bug fixes etc.

Now the only simple solution seems to be multiple local repos or clones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with mercurial out of the box. As have been suggested there are several ways of selecting what files you want to commit. To get this function via the commit message template, you would need an extension or a shell script wrapping the commit command.  Here's one way to do that:

```
[alias]
ci = ! hg-partial-commit
```

hg-partial-commit:

```
#!/bin/sh
# partial commit

edit=$(mktemp ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/$(basename $0).XXXXXXXXXXXX)
filelist=$(mktemp ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/$(basename $0).XXXXXXXXXXXX)
logmessage=$(mktemp ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/$(basename $0).XXXXXXXXXXXX)
cleanup="rm -f '$edit' '$filelist' '$logmessage'"
trap "$cleanup" 0 1 2 3 15

(
    echo user: $(hg debugconfig ui.username)
    echo branch: $(hg branch)
    hg parents --template 'parent: {rev}:{node|short}  {author}  {date|isodate}\n'
    echo
    echo 'Enter commit message.  Select files to commit by deleting lines:'
    hg status 'set:not unknown()' | sed -e 's/^/@/'
) | sed -e 's/^/HG: /' >"$edit"

${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}} "$edit"
egrep -v '^HG:' "$edit" >"$logmessage"
egrep '^HG: @' "$edit" | cut -c8- >"$filelist"

hg commit -l "$logmessage" "listfile:$filelist"
$cleanup
```

Comment: Thanks for the script, This is the simplest and easiest for me, other than modifying the hg source code.

Comment: Not entirely true... Look @rudy-matela answer

Comment: @NemoStein Maybe I misunderstood the question. Of course you can check in only certain files; there are several ways, as I said. What you can't do with unmodified Mercurial is to have a sort of interactive review of commit candidates. That's the answer I gave, in case it was useful for the OP's workflow.

I don't like to overinterpret SO questions. Many people arrive at these posts for years later with all kinds of use cases. There's an argument in favor of answering unasked questions to solve a more fundamental problem, but it's also useful to answer exactly the question that was asked.

Answer (score 4):

Use `hg ci <files>...` to commit only certain files in your working directory.

Comment: this will work with one or two files....... what if I have 20 files and I want to check in 10 without spelling them out on cmd line?

Comment: If you don't want to type 10 filenames, use shell regular expressions to pick out the ones you want: `hg ci sql/* web/*.{htm,php}`, or whatever. If that's still more typing than you can handle, use `hg status -q` to get a list of modified files; copy-paste it into an editor and edit it into the hg command you want. (Then you can copy-paste it back to the commandline)

Comment: I really think that this is the least effort with best benefits answer. Installing/enabling extensions can be difficult to newcomers and working with branches isn't always practical for low count of files, but if you really need to modify more a two digit number of files, branches is the way to go...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pick file by file you can use the [record command](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RecordExtension).  It ships with mercurial, but you have to turn it on if you want to use it by putting: `record=` in the `[extensions]` section of your `~/.hgrc`.

It goes hunk by hunk, but you can answer for a whole file:

```
y - record this change
n - skip this change

s - skip remaining changes to this file
f - record remaining changes to this file

d - done, skip remaining changes and files
a - record all changes to all remaining files
q - quit, recording no changes

? - display help
```

I'll point out that if you're committing some files but not others it's certain that you've not run your test suite on the one change without the other, but maybe that doesn't apply in your case.

Answer (score 2):

The real problem here is the fact that you're doing changes related to different tasks jumbled together. Mercurial has a few ways you can keep things separate.

**Task Branches**

Suppose you've been working on a task and you've checked in a few times since you last pulled, but things aren't ready to share yet.

```
o----o----B----o----o----o
```

Here, `B` is the revision where you started your changes. What we do is (after making sure our current changes are checked in):

```
> hg update -r B
<do our work on the other task>
> hg commit
```

We've now created a new branch with the changes for this task separated from the changes for our original task.

```
o----o----B----o----o----o
           \
            ----o
```

We can do this for as many different tasks as we want. The only problem is that sometimes remembering which branch is which can be awkward. This is where features like [bookmarks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Bookmarks/) come in useful. A bookmark is a tag which moves forward as commits are made so that it always points at the head of a branch.

**Mercurial Queues**

[MQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) adds the ability to work on changes incrementally and move between them by `push`ing and `pop`ing then off a stack (or "Queue" I guess). So if I had a set of uncommitted changes that I needed to split up I'd:

```
> hg qrecord taska
> hg qrecord taskb
> hg qrecord taskc
```

I'd use the [record](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RecordExtension) extension (or more likely the [crecord](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CrecordExtension) extension) to select which parts of files I want to select.

If I needed to go back to `taska` and make some changes:

```
> hg qpop; hg qpop    # pop two off the queue to go back to task a
<Do changes>
> hg qrefresh         # update task a with the new changes
```

When I want to turn the queue into normal changesets:

```
> hg qpush or hg qpop # get the changes I want converted onto the queue
> hg qfinish -a       # converts mq changes to normal changesets
```

---

There's other methods too, but that will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

You will unavoidably have to either specify the files that you want to add or the files you want to leave out. If you have a lot of files, as you indicate above, the following steps will simplify the procedure (I'm assuming a UNIX-ish system here, Windows would be slightly different).

First, generate a list of changed files:

```
hg status -mard -n >/tmp/changedlist.txt
```

The `-mard` options will list all files that were modified, added, removed, or delated. The `-n` option will list them without the status prefix so that all you have is a raw list of files.

Second, edit `/tmp/changedlist.txt` with your favorite text editor so that it contains only the files you wish to commit.

Third, commit these files:

```
hg commit `cat /tmp/changedlist.txt`
```

You will be able to review the files to be committed before actually performing the commit.

Alternatively, you can add more files to a commit incrementally by using

```
`hg commit --amend file...`
```

Here, `hg commit --amend` will not create a new commit, but add the new files to the existing commit. So, you start out with committing just a couple of files, then incrementally adding more until you are done. This still requires you to type all of them in.

For yet another alternative, you can use Mercurial Queues to split a commit in more sophisticated ways, but that's a bit more of an advanced topic.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was hopping that if I can just delete the lines in the commit message , hg will remove them from checking in. like cvs I think. I guess it is not possible with hg